# Change parameters of a javascript function/"class" asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, attributes

So I have some JS code that I ideally want to run as a custom "object" but I can't seem to do so due to nature of JS.

So I've followed a blog somewhere online and have written this (what seems to me as elegant but probably isn't) solution:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbservice = function () {
    this.connected = false;
    this.connection_error = false;
    this.status_messages = [];
    this.connect = function() {
        mongoose.connect('Laaaadeedaaaa');
        var db = mongoose.connection;
        db.on('error', function() {
            this.status_messages.push('Nooo! Connection Error');
            console.error.bind(console, 'Nooo! Connection Error: ');
            this.connection_error = true;  
        });
        db.once('open', function() {
            this.status_messages.push('Successfully connected to the database!');
            console.log('Successfully connected to the database!');
            this.connected = true;
        });
    };
    //DB (db.runCommand({whatsmyuri: 1}))
    this.createUser = function(user_in, password_in) {
        require("./data/models/user");
        var User = mongoose.model('User');
        var newUser = new User({ username: user_in, password: password_in, date_created: Date() });
        newUser.save(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                this.status_messages.push('User creation error!');
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                this.status_messages.push('Success!');
                console.log('Success:', data);
            }
        });
    };
};
module.exports = dbservice;
```

I try to call this as so:

```
var cur_service = new dbservice();
cur_service.connect();
setTimeout(function() { 
    console.log("Connected!");
    console.log(cur_service.connected);
},3000);
```

So what essentially happens is that `this.connect` is run successfully (yay) and it completes itself quickly (because the mongoose functions are asynchronous). About 1 second later, the console outputs `Successfully connected to the database` as expected. However, when the timer ticks, `cur_service.connected` is still false which is confusing as I've set it to be true and the async function has fully completed. This means the `this.blah =` format isn't appropriate in async returns. So how do you go about solving this? Is there another basic syntax error that I am not noticing? I've just started js development (having only really done iOS/Desktop/C++) so this is all really new and abstract :P

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: *"I have some JS code that I ideally want to run as a class but obviously can't do so due to JS."`* -- Sorry, what?

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. That aside, it's not entirely clear what you're ultimately trying to accomplish. You also need to understand the use of *this* in JS is probably not what you're used to.

Comment: Lots of problems here.  `this` is not going to have a useful value in `dbservice()` if it is just a plain function call, not a new object creation.  And, `this` will get lost in all the callback functions because it is not typically preserved in a callback.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, woops, I've changed this slightly! Didn't mean at all to make this come out as really arrogant - apolgies! I hope I've clarified it!

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton & @jfriend00 - right it looks like you guys have hit the nail on the head! I would have thought that `this` always refers to the original object which called it but I now realise why that was a very silly assumption haha! Many thanks for your help - I'll try and see if this leads to any improvement.

Comment: What "nature" of JS are you referring to? How is it preventing you from doing what you're trying to do? (To be honest I'm not sure what that is-it looks like you're trying to code JS like its a different language besides JS.)

Comment: I'm very used to a class based language like C++, where you define a set of attributes and a bunch of methods for a single object - this is the approach I'm taking to JS as well (although its pretty clear, as you say, that this isn't the right way!). I quite like the idea of also being able to import the relevant "code" from a js file straight into another js file without the need to go through and reference all the script sources on a webpage. The real reason why I was implementing this method was because I couldn't, for the life of me, see how I was importing stuff incorrectly in the HTML!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you think you can't do in JS. With regards to "importing" you probably want any of the numerous require-ish libraries. You may want to take a step back and read up on modern JavaScript development practices before biting off larger (conceptually) projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

callback functions usually do not have the same `this` value as the parent scope.  There are many ways to deal with this, but a simple way is to save the `this` value in a parent scoped variable named something like `self` and then reference `self` from the callback rather than referencing `this`.  An example of that is here:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbservice = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.connected = false;
    this.connection_error = false;
    this.status_messages = [];
    this.connect = function(cb) {
        mongoose.connect('Laaaadeedaaaa');
        var db = mongoose.connection;
        db.on('error', function(err) {
            // use self in here to reference the parent object
            self.status_messages.push('Nooo! Connection Error');
            console.error.bind(console, 'Nooo! Connection Error: ');
            self.connection_error = true;  
            callback(err);
        });
        db.once('open', function() {
            self.status_messages.push('Successfully connected to the database!');
            console.log('Successfully connected to the database!');
            self.connected = true;
            // signal completion of the connection
            callback(null);
        });
    };
    //DB (db.runCommand({whatsmyuri: 1}))
    this.createUser = function(user_in, password_in, callback) {
        var self = this;
        require("./data/models/user");
        var User = mongoose.model('User');
        var newUser = new User({ username: user_in, password: password_in, date_created: Date() });
        newUser.save(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                self.status_messages.push('User creation error!');
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                self.status_messages.push('Success!');
                console.log('Success:', data);
            }
            callback(err, data);
        });
    };
};
module.exports = dbservice;
```

---

In general, I think you want to be communicating async results back as arguments to a completion callback, NOT as object state.  This is because you have no idea when the object state is set or not set.  You only know that when a completion callback is called so at that point, you may as well just pass it as arugments to the callback as I've shown above.

This could work only if you instantiated a new object when calling dbservice such as:

```
var dbservice = require('dbservice');
var d = new dbservice();
d.connect(function(err) {
   if (!err) {
        d.createUser("bob", "password", function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                // user created here
            }
        });
     }
});
```

---

Another issue you have here is that you should be using callbacks or promises to signal the end of an asynchronous operation, not a timer guess for when the operation would be done.  I've added some callbacks to your existing code to show you the general concept, but you also have to be diligent about returning errors properly.

If you're really going to be writing much asynchronous code like this, you really want to learn how to use promises because they make asynchronous chaining and error handling a LOT easier, once you promisify your interfaces (which means converting them to return promises rather than take straight callbacks) and learn how to use promises to best advantage.

Comment: @Imranahmed - I added callbacks and `self` to your code and showed you an example of how to safely call it without using timers to guess when it might be done.  This is a crude example with your code just to illustrate the general concepts.  I would personally design it differently myself.

Comment: Many thanks for the elaboration @jfriend00 - this is definitely very helpful! I'll take a look at trying to implement this now. 

Also, thank you for the advice wrt. callbacks! The real reason why I placed this in a timer was just to debug what exactly was going wrong inside the code. I understand why this would not be appropriate when running a website.

Comment: Oh wow these callbacks are incredible! Thank you so much for this! I never knew these could exist like this haha!

Comment: @ImranAhmed - wait until you learn how to use Promises instead of callbacks.  Even better.